# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot clean commit: Staging file does not exist. Filink Streaming FileSink to HDFS Path

Tags: apache-flink

During streaming Job execution time, got below exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while confirming checkpoint
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.notifyCheckpointComplete(StreamTask.java:952)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$notifyCheckpointCompleteAsync$7(StreamTask.java:924)
at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$asCallable$5(FunctionUtils.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.run(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:87)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:78)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:261)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:186)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:487)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:470)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot clean commit: Staging file does not exist.**
at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopRecoverableFsDataOutputStream$HadoopFsCommitter.commit(HadoopRecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:250)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.onSuccessfulCompletionOfCheckpoint(Bucket.java:300)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.commitUpToCheckpoint(Buckets.java:216)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.notifyCheckpointComplete(StreamingFileSink.java:415)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.notifyCheckpointComplete(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:130)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$notifyCheckpointComplete$8(StreamTask.java:936)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:101)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.notifyCheckpointComplete(StreamTask.java:930)
... 12 more

Please let me know, if anyone faced the above issue.